# jQuery, get the value in a label

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of this label:

```
  <label id="name" class="sub_heading"><?php echo $_SESSION['lastname'].", ".$_SESSION['firstname']; ?></label>
```

for some reason this:

```
  var name = ("#name").val();
```

is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use either [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as follows:

```
var name = $("#name").html();
```

Method `val()` is suitable only for form elements (e.g. `<input>`, `<select>`, etc).

Comment: even with html() and text() it still does nothing

Comment: nevermind, this worked perfect, it was a syntax error on my part

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation, `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) should be used only on form controls (`input`, `button`, `select`, `textarea`).  If you want the contents of an element, use `.text()` or `.html()` as appropriate.